# Weird prefix while in SSH

Tags: ssh, terminal

When I ssh into a particular server, I get a weird prefix that looks like a box with the characters 001B, and a "k" behind the vertical "0B". See the picture below.

[image]

How do I fix this?

I think it must be a setting in a bashrc or bash_profile somewhere

Comment: This is yet another variant on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418157/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248299/ , and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x001b` is hexadecimal for the escape ASCII sequence. Your prompt contains one or several escape sequences that the terminal can not display. Make sure that your `TERM` variable is set correctly, or set a more sane primary prompt (`PS1`) in you shell startup script (probably `~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`).

Comment: Thank you. The TERM variable was indeed the problem. For some reason it seems that "screen-256color" doesn't play nice with ssh. Are there any work-arounds? I like the coloring when I am not ssh'ing.

Comment: screen-256color is meant to be used in `screen` (GNU Screen).   If you're not using `screen`, and you have a terminal that supports 256 colors, you could try `xterm-256color`, and if that looks weird too, you could try `xterm-color`.  If your terminal isn't xterm-compatible, and you still want colors, you may be able to use the terminal definition for `ansi` (`export TERM=ansi`)

Comment: setting TERM=xterm-256color fixes the issue, as well as TERM=ansi. Both fixes work

Comment: @RDev `toe -a` (on Ubuntu at least) will list _all_ supported terminals.  Pick one that most closely resembles the one you are using. TimKennedy's suggestions seems sound to me.